# Sitecore Parameter templates - cannot access image field

Tags: .net, sitecore, sitecore7

I am looking at parameter templates in sitecore for a rendering item that I have on page.

I'm wanting the editor to be able to add the rendering several times to the page but they can define different properties to each rendering so as to make a reusable item.

I have defined fields for:

Title - textfield
Colour - textfield
Icon - textfield
Image - imagefield
Pinned - checkbox

Using the code shown below I am able to retrieve the textfield elements but having nothing returned for the image type; my intention is to also have the icons as a drop down list of preset items and I have a feeling this issue may apply to that also...

Thanks for any assistance

```
public partial class jonstest : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    private NameValueCollection parameters;
    public virtual NameValueCollection Parameters
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.parameters == null)
            {
                var parameters = this.Attributes["sc_parameters"];
                this.parameters = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)
                                      ? new NameValueCollection()
                                      : Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(parameters);
            }
            return this.parameters;
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rawParameters = Attributes["sc_parameters"];
        var parameters = Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ParseUrlParameters(rawParameters);
        var title = parameters["Title"];
        var colour = "tile-" + parameters["Colour"];
        var icon = "fa-" + parameters["Icon"];
        //var image = parameters["Image"];

        var image = this.Rendering.Parameters["Image"];



        TitleText.Text = title;
        ColourValue.Attributes["class"] += " " + colour.ToLower();
        IconValue.Attributes["class"] += " " + icon.ToLower();

        foreach (string key in this.Parameters.Keys)
        {
            Image.Text += "Key=" + key + ";Value=" + this.Parameters[key] + ", ";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use Rendering Parameters for this and instead use Datasources for your rendering. Each one can have it's own datasources and then allows things like testing, personalisation and translation. None of these are possible using Rendering Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As Jammykam pointed out please don't use rendering parameters for this kind of information. This should be stored on the data source where it can be properly stored and language versioned etc.

However if you feel hell bent on doing it this way then please see this previous answer [Sitecore - Image field in parameter template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824397/sitecore-image-field-in-parameter-template)

Just remember that the rendering parameters are in essence simple key value pairs provided as a url encoded string. Which is not ideal for passing complex data.

Cheers, Bo